# jQuery - hasClass of a button works with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap checkbox button to have a button group.
When a user clicks on one of the buttons, it becomes active.

I use the function below to check which button is active and which is not and then use this data in the rest of the function.

as you can see in the jsfiddle, the results are delayed, and it would be correct if I would change `is` to `was`. But I need the test in the function I'm using, not on the next call to the function.

Can someone explain to me why this happen and if my `hasClass` check is correct for this kind of situation?

HTML:

```
<div class="box btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button data-filter="a" id="a" name="button" type="button" class="btn">A</button>
    <button data-filter="b" id="b" name="button" type="button" class="btn">B</button>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
$(".box").on('click', function(){
    alert("a is " + ($("#a").hasClass("active") ? "active" : "not-active"));
    alert("b is " + ($("#b").hasClass("active") ? "active" : "not-active"));
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AvXUb/3/)

Comment: That's because your javascript is executing before bootstrap has set the classes.

Comment: so how would I test if a user clicked on a button?

Comment: You're already testing that, but setting the classes happens after you've checked it. All you really need to do is defer it, like so -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/AvXUb/4/) and it should work?

Comment: Where can I read on what is defer? why does setting timeout work in this case?

Comment: using the timeout, how do I use variables I set inside the setTimeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap automatic bindings works at `document` level, which means that your `click` event at `.box` level still doesn't know about the change of state of the buttons.

You can drop the automatic binding removing the `data-toggle` attribute for this group of checkboxes and use `.button()` as documented in the [Twitter Bootstrap API](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons).

```
<div class="box btn-group">
    <button data-filter="a" id="a" name="button" type="button" class="btn">A</button>
    <button data-filter="b" id="b" name="button" type="button" class="btn">B</button>
</div>​
```

```
$(".box").on('click', '.btn', function(){
    $(this).button("toggle");    
    alert("a is " + ($("#a").hasClass("active") ? "active" : "not active"));
    alert("b is " + ($("#b").hasClass("active") ? "active" : "not active"));
});
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye22d/)